# How to programmatically get custom theme values via Robolectric

Tags: android, android-theme, robolectric

I'm able to access custom color theme values in my app via:

```
private int getTextColorFromTheme(int textAppearanceAttrResId, int state) {
    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();

>>>>/* missing TypedValue.data in Robolectric!! */
    Resources.Theme theme = mContext.getTheme();

    // textAppearanceAttrResId is a reference, so it is required to be retrieved this way.
    theme.resolveAttribute(textAppearanceAttrResId, typedValue, true);

    int[] textColorAttr = new int[]{android.R.attr.textColor};
    int indexOfAttrTextColor = 0;
    TypedArray a = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(typedValue.data, textColorAttr);
    ColorStateList csl = a.getColorStateList(indexOfAttrTextColor);

>>>>/* NPE thrown here in Robolectric! */
    int color = csl.getColorForState(new int[]{state}, -1);

    a.recycle();

    return color;
}
```

But Robolectric throws an NPE when trying to access the ColorStateList.  I've noticed mContext.getTheme() returns a theme with a TypedArray whose data is 0.

mContext is set up previously in setup():

```
    ActivityController<MyActivity> activityController = Robolectric.buildActivity(MyActivity.class).attach();
    MyActivity activity = activityController.get();

    activity.setTheme(com.sudocoder.android.theme.R.style.Theme_Mine);
    activityController.create().start().resume().visible();

    mContext = activity;
```

Answer (score 0):

We've had huge problems getting certain kinds of resources to work with Robolectric at my current team.  Seems like resources of type  and  either throw a ResourceNotFound exception or return an incorrect value (like null or zero).  Depending on your project setup, you might be able to use Mockito to mock the theme, but aside from that I don't know if there's much to be done- perhaps someone else will know more.